# Not all Price tier visible to select in WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create WebApp in azure. I can see only 3 price tier and NO option to select other price tier. If i read the corresponding docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest
it says accepted values B1, B2, B3, D1, F1, FREE, P1, P1V2, P2, P2V2, P3, P3V2, PC2, PC3, PC4, S1, S2, S3, SHARED.
How do i select say PC3 from azure portal UI?

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark).

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the azure portal, search for `web app for containers`, choose it, then you will be able to create a web app for container with `PC3` pricing tier service plan.

[image]

[image]